# Multi-level, creating second level variable

Tags: data-transformation, spss, multilevel-analysis

I have some trouble coding my data for multi-level analysis. I'm doing research on test results of children. These children are grouped within classes, within schools. I'm using class as the highest level in my multi-level models, however, class is only measured by assigning the name of their class to the student. This way, some children belong to the class '2C', some to '2' others to '2B' and so on. The problem is that different schools use the same name for their class, so I can't take this variable as my subject in SPSS. What I want to do is give each respondent a score on a new variable 'class' where all children in the same school, in the same class get the same score. I have no idea how to do this...

For clarification (English is not my native language and I have some trouble making myself clear), here's the structure of my data:

```
ID     School     Class
01     1          2A
02     1          2A
03     1          2A
04     1          2B
05     1          2B
06     2          2A
07     2          2A
08     3          002A
09     3          002A
```

In this example, I want all children in school '1', in class '2A' to get the score '1' on a new variable, those in school '1', in class '2B' to get the score '2' and so on.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to concatenate the variables `school` and `class`, because you are sure that their combinations are your level 2 identifiers. This approach further does not involve manual assignment of codes or anything.

Assuming that your variable `school` is numeric and the variable `class` is a string, you should do something like this:

```
* Define new string variable of width 20.
str level2var (a20).

* Concatenate the two other variables into the newly defined variable.
compute level2var eq concat(str(school, f2.0), rtrim(class)).
exe.
```

The function `concat` is to concatenate multiple strings. The function `str` is to convert a numeric variable to a string. I used `f2.0` to state that this string can have 2 numbers before the decimal point, and 0 numbers after the point. The function `rtrim` is to make sure that from the existing string of `class`, excess spaces on the right are trimmed.

Good luck!